# Prepare doesn't get called on segue (Swift 4.2)

Tags: navigation, segue, xcode10, swift4.2

I've searched for an answer here, but wasn't able to find the exact same issue I have, please help me so sort it out.

The problem is that when I create a separate view and try to make a segue using storyboard and navigation view controller, the segue itself works fine, but

`override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

does not get called. To make my example as minimal as possible I've make a toy app to show what's going on.

[That's how the overall storyboard schema looks like. **ViewController** is embedded in **NavigationController**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N90cD.png)

[Segue is made with ctrl + SecondViewController, **identifier is set**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jZ6X.png)

[Custom class for **SecondViewController is set**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozsS7.png)

View controllers have the following implementation:
Main view controller sets the title of the only button:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button.setTitle("Awesome title", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

On button press the label is meant to be updated from the button's title:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("SecondViewController viewDidLoad method")
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print(print("SecondViewController prepare method"))
        if let text = (sender as? UIButton)?.titleLabel?.text {
            label.text = text
        }
    }
}
```

I intentionally put two print statements to show that `viewDidLoad` actually gets called, but not `prepare`.

[Here is a gif showing how the app works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZRir.gif) As you may see label on the second view doesn't get updated either.

I've also tried to set segue [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtbFn.png), then create an `@IBAction` function and manually call `performSegue`:

```
@IBAction func onButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Id", sender: self)
}
```

Please help me to understand and solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what's wrong. For those who still feel confused by the way segues work in IOS have a look at the diagram below:

[Segues in IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZcIr.jpg) (taken from [here](https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/))

Note that `prepare (for: sender)` is located **in View A, not in View B**. This is critical since it gets triggered before the actual segue is performed. Moreover, if you assign some values to *View B* parameter (for instance `UIIMageView`), then the view gets rendered considering these changes.